# Disable a bundle in Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, mobile, bundle

I would like to disable a bundle in Symfony2. 
Now I am using the Braincrafted BoostrapBundle for desktops, but I want to disable this bundle for mobile devices. I only use JQuery Mobile for mobile devices. The problem is that forms have some bootstrap styles that I don't want to use.

Comment: You can try with CSS @mediaQueries. Or also a JS Library like https://github.com/ded/bowser

Comment: not if this helps... https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle

Comment: I use that bundle (Suncat2000), but forms have always bootstrap styles ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bundle you mentioned in your comment (MobileDetectBundle) to not load the Bootstrap style sheets in your layout:

`{% if not is_mobile() %}
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endif %}`